# Don't expand "Most Used" accordion item when adding new block

Tags: block-editor, user-interface

In the block editor, when clicking to add a new block, the popup shows an accordion with the first item expanded ("Most Used").

How can I change it so that all the items are initially collapsed?

Comment: I looked into this briefly a couple months ago and couldn't come up with a good solution, I ended up just added some CSS to hide the Most Used section.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis Yeah I rarely use that item so it just gets in my way. I'll set a stylish rule for that, thanks for the tip.

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: @TomJNowell As I said it just gets in the way. Every time I open the "add block" popup it automatically shows the common group, and I almost always end up choosing something from another group. So it just adds friction. It's a small nuisance but after stumbling over it a hundred times I decided to do something about it. The userstyles approach is good enough if there's no better way.

Comment: As an aside, I'd mention this on the Gutenberg GH repo, it's valuable user feedback that might get them to change how it works, or at least provide the option or a design fix

Comment: @TomJNowell Good idea... done.

Comment: Here is the ticket: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/19070